# Log to different files with NLog and configure it with NLog Config XML

Tags: logging, nlog

For some business purposes I have to create different log files and write them to different files. [1 to 1000 dynamically change] .It may be crazy but that is what the business wants.

I am able to manage it using NLog programatically : I create different Target for different log files programatically and create named loggers for each of them.

The problem is that now I am not able to configure NLog externally : Suppose that I will change log files layout. [ Now I should do it from code ] I should have to create my own config file which I do not want.

I try to write to use NConfig file variable definition, but NLog does not allow to reach variable definitions from code.

Is it possible [ any trick] to create loggers with different files with NLog Config file, without writing all logs-targets to NLog File? [ I am not able to add all loggers to Nlog config since I do not know how many I will create, but I have a pattern to create them ]

**My Log File Creation Pattern :**

I have different channels in my app : For each request I create a new channel with its own channel:

- Channel1.log Channel2.log Channel3.log .... ChannelN.log

Answer (score 2):

You can use single file target and incorporate a layout renderer into its `fileName` parameter. This target will choose one of the several files based on the value that layout renderer have provided.

```xml
<target xsi:type="File"
          layout="${message}"
          fileName="${baseDir}\Log\channel${channelId}.log"
          createDirs="true" />
```

where `${channelId}` is the layout renderer which provides different value for each channel. This value should be obtained somehow from the context of the request.

You can look for the existing [layout renderers](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Layout-Renderers) to see if any of them fits your needs or write your own specific renderer.